# Метод Accept класса Socket c#

Tags: c#, сокет

Как запустить метод Accept в неблокирующем режиме?
Проблема: при прослушивании порта в ожидании подключения программа приостанавливает выполнение кода.

Сам код:

```
try
        {
            sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            sListener.Listen(10);

            int count = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                count += 1;
                Socket handler = sListener.Accept();

                Thread thrConn = new Thread(()=>doChat(handler));
                thrConn.Start();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во-первых сервер и клиент все-таки не одно приложение, но если хочется именно так, то читайте про асинхронное программирование и метод [BeginAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y709t3b.aspx) применительно к текущей задаче.

Comment: Конечно, не один, но сервер у меня выполняет и другие функции, помимо взаимодействия с клиентом, с которыми будет работать администратор программы. Ну я дипломку пишу, а с сокетами раньше никогда не работал, вот и сложности на каждом шагу.